# Difficulties setting up maven project using AWS encryption SDK

Tags: java, maven

I have the following pom file in my maven project on IntelliJ-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aws-encryption</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-encryption</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-encryption-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
             <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
             <version>1.11.327</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
             <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
             <version>1.65</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
             <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
             <version>1.11.765</version>
         </dependency>

     </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

And the following class file -

```
package com.aws.encrypt;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    private static String keyArn;
    private static String data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keyArn = args[0];
        data = args[1];

        // Instantiate the SDK
        final AwsCrypto crypto = new AwsCrypto();

        // Set up the KmsMasterKeyProvider backed by the default credentials
        final KmsMasterKeyProvider prov = KmsMasterKeyProvider.builder().withKeysForEncryption(keyArn).build();

        // Encrypt the data
        //
        // Most encrypted data should have an associated encryption context
        // to protect integrity. This sample uses placeholder values.
        //
        // For more information see:
        // blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2LZ6WBJJANTNW/How-to-Protect-the-Integrity-of-Your-Encrypted-Data-by-Using-AWS-Key-Management
        final Map<String, String> context = Collections.singletonMap("Example", "String");

        final String ciphertext = crypto.encryptString(prov, data, context).getResult();
        System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + ciphertext);

        // Decrypt the data
        final CryptoResult<String, KmsMasterKey> decryptResult = crypto.decryptString(prov, ciphertext);

        // Before returning the plaintext, verify that the customer master key that
        // was used in the encryption operation was the one supplied to the master key provider.
        if (!decryptResult.getMasterKeyIds().get(0).equals(keyArn)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong key ID!");
        }

        // Also, verify that the encryption context in the result contains the
        // encryption context supplied to the encryptString method. Because the
        // SDK can add values to the encryption context, don't require that
        // the entire context matches.
        for (final Map.Entry<String, String> e : context.entrySet()) {
            if (!e.getValue().equals(decryptResult.getEncryptionContext().get(e.getKey()))) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong Encryption Context!");
            }
        }

        // Now we can return the plaintext data
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decryptResult.getResult());
    }

}
```

It seems all the dependency jars were not downloaded.
I can only find aws-encryption-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in my local repository.
Not sure why the others did not get downloaded. I tried mvn clean install as well.

I don't see any issues with my repository settings -

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository</localRepository>

</settings>
```

What could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the maven debug flag?
eg

```
mvn clean install -X
```

it may give you some clue about what actually happens under the hood
hth
update:
dependency management is for grouping dependencies for *child* projects, in a *parent* pom. If this is not the case one can just use dependencies alone.

Comment: No errors. If I comment out the code in my Main.java class, build happens successfully. I expect the dependency jars to get downloaded, but those aren't.

Comment: try to remove dependencymanagement node in your pom. Use just dependencies

Comment: glad to hear it!